# Assign a discrete i-value from a array to a variable with a discrete name (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, variables, assign

I would like to know how I can assign a value out of an array[i] to a variable with a defined name. Like char priceapple = value of array[23]:

```
  for(;;){

    // either assign discrete variables discrete data from an array:

    int newvar0 = value[i]; // assing value[0] to  newvar0;
    int newvar1 = value[i]; // assing value[1] to  newvar1;
    int newvar2 = value[i]; // assing value[2] to  newvar2;

    // or create a new variable with new name:

    int newvar + i = value[i]; // obviously I dont know weather this is possible.      

    i = i++;

  }
```

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Arrays are made exactly for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are made exactly for this use case

```
for(;;){

    // either assign discrete variables discrete data from an array:
    std::array<int, 100> newvar;
    newvar[0] = value[i]; // assing value[0] to  newvar0;
    newvar[1] = value[i]; // assing value[1] to  newvar1;
    newvar[2] = value[i]; // assing value[2] to  newvar2;

    // or create a new variable with new name:

    newvar[i] = value[i]; // obviously I dont know weather this is possible.      

    i = i++;

  }
```

Use an unordered_map if you don't know the size

```
for(;;){

    // either assign discrete variables discrete data from an array:
    std::unordered_map<int, int> newvar;
    newvar[0] = value[i]; // assing value[0] to  newvar0;
    newvar[1] = value[i]; // assing value[1] to  newvar1;
    newvar[2] = value[i]; // assing value[2] to  newvar2;

    // or create a new variable with new name:

    newvar[i] = value[i]; // obviously I dont know weather this is possible.      

    i = i++;

  }
```